# How to pass json data to Class variable in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a class Projects

```
export class Projects {
project_id: number;
project_name: string;
category_id: number;
project_type: string;
start_date: Date;
completion_date: Date;
working_status: string;
project_info: string;
area: string;
address: string;
city: string;}
```

Its Service class is

```
@Injectable()
export class ProjectsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  //http://localhost:9090/projectInfo
private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:9090/projectInfo';

public findAll() {
  return this.http.get(this.apiUrl);
 }

 getProducts(): Observable<ProjectsModule[]> {
  return this.http.get<ProjectsModule[]>(this.apiUrl);
}
```

Component is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectsService } from '../projects.service';
import{Projects} from '../projects';
import { plainToClass, Transform, Expose, Type, Exclude } from 'class-transformer';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-list',
  templateUrl: './project-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-list.component.css'],
  providers: [ProjectsService]
})
export class ProjectListComponent implements OnInit {

private projects:Projects[]=[];
stringObject: any;
  constructor(
   private projectsService: ProjectsService) { }
   vandana='rahul';
   
  ngOnInit() {
   this.getAllProjects();
   }


 getAllProjects() {
   this.projectsService.getProducts().subscribe((data: Projects[])=> {
      this.stringObject =JSON.stringify(data)
      let newTodo = Object.assign(new Projects(), data); 
      this.projects=  <Projects[]>this.stringObject;
      console.log("data  -"+ this.projects)
      console.log("Array  -"+ this.stringObject)
      console.log("data  -"+ this.projects[1].project_info)
      },
      
   err => {
   console.log(err);
   } 
   
  );
 
   }
```

When i am trying to read newTodo.project_id (or any property of class Projects) it is undefined
but newtodo is returning jsondata

output is

[image]

Please help me in getting values newtodo.project_id, newtodo.project_name and so on

Comment: You're assigning a string value to `this.projects`. Why?

Comment: trying to parse data to Projects class somehow and trying every possible way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a JSON string to `this.projects`.

The JSON string is `[{"projectId": 1, ... }]`.

So:

- `this.projects[1]` evaluates to `{` (i.e. the second character in the string)
- `"{".project_id` evaluates to `undefined`

You should assign the data itself to `this.projects`:

```
this.projects = data;
```

And then keep in mind that arrays in JavaScript are zero-based. Since you only have one object in your array, you'd have to print the `projectId` as follows:

```
console.log(this.projects[0].projectId);
```

Also, the properties of your `Projects` class don't match your JSON at all. Furthermore, `Projects` should probably be named `Project`, and should be an interface instead of a class.

Comment: has done changes .. it is giving value .. undefined

Comment: has done changes .. it is giving value .. undefined

Comment: Your class definition (which should be an interface) does not match your JSON. At all.

Comment: to read it in html file  can i use  <tr *ngFor="let project of projects  "></tr>
      <td> Value is {{project.projectId}}</td>